# wordpress dynamic and static page

Tags: wordpress, templates, wordpress-theming

Ive created my first wp-theme, my front page is dynamic with posts etc. I want to create a page that is diffrent than the main one. A page template that has static content as the main content and posts on the side. example; I want to create an about us page and have a static text that tells the audience what we do but I also want posts on the side. Ive created the dynamic part of the page but I'm having trouble with the static part.

This is how the dynamic part looks like:

```
    <div class="latest-posts eightcol">
      <?php  the_post(); ?>
         <article class="post">
            <h2><a title="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

    <div class="entry-meta links-turquoise">
      <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> &mdash;


           <span class="author"> <?php the_author(); ?>utvecklare</span>
              </div><!-- .entry-meta .links-turquoise -->
      <div>
         <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
         </article>

      </div><!-- .latest-posts .eightcol -->
```

What I dont know how to write is the static part. I want to create this template so that I can apply the same layout to more then one page.

I hope you understand what I'm looking for.
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to create a page template all you need is to add the name of the template as a comment in the top of the template file like so:

```
<?php 

/* Template Name: Contact us */

//code
```

It will then be recognized by your wordpress editor, and you'll be able to choose it as a page template

[image: Contact Us template]

You can load the page static content before you load the posts, that is before the loop, simply by calling `the_post()` and `the_content()` since *the default post is the page that was loaded*. (try `var_dump($post)` and see for yourself). In case you want to call it after the loop you can use `wp_reset_query();` to return to the starting point

Comment: yes I did that, I copied my page.php and created an about.php but what I dont know is how to change the dynamic content area into a static one. It may sound stupid but I'm stuck, I really dont know how to format the code

Comment: I'm not sure that answers my problem, I'm trying to add an editable static non-changing content area.

Comment: and that's exactly what I am addressing. Once you've created this template you can use it multiple times with different pages, and each time you'll get a different static content, i.e. the current page content, that you'll be able to edit on your volition.

Comment: I did not even realize that it answers my question.. Thank you Matanya